# Term for what OK, Cancel and Apply buttons do, as a group

Tags: wpf, mvvm, naming-conventions, terminology, naming

I am guessing that most people refer to these buttons simply by their names when they speak, saying "OKCancel" or "OKCancelApply". Is there a special term that Microsoft or anyone else uses to refer to this strip of buttons?

**Context of the Question and Other Notes**:

(Mvvm/Wpf) I have a view model which is currently called *CancelCommitViewModel*. It contains a collection of *UserCommandViewModel* items. There is one *UserCommand* for each button that is to be displayed (titled "_OK", "_Cancel" and "_Apply"). Each *UserCommand* has a reference called Command which is a reference to an application command in *CancelCommitViewModel*.

*CancelCommit* always shows the OK button. Cancel and Apply are optional. This encapsulates the associated logic; other view models use *CancelCommit* as a component. I don't think that the composite will always be a dialog, so I'm not going to call it *DialogCommitViewModel*.

**Naming Ideas**:

- *CancelCommitViewModel*. Reference named CancelCommit when compositing. "{Binding CancelCommit.HasChanges}" "{Binding CancelCommit.IsCancelAvailable}" etc.
- *OKCancelApplyViewModel*. This is terrible.
- *CommitViewModel*. Nice and short; too short though - doesn't convey meaning well enough.
- *TransactionViewModel*. Implies something different.
- I might go with *CommitCancel* instead of *CancelCommit* since the Cancel part is optional, but I still want it in there because it is the other major function that is represented.
- *ConfirmCancel*. Am I confirming or committing when I press OK or Apply? Maybe OK = Confirm, Cancel = Cancel and Apply = Commit?
- I am going with *CommitCancel* since those are the 2 major operations being represented. Confirm (OK) is basically just a call to Commit.

Comment: We just call these "dialog buttons", which gives us the opportunity to lump Help in there too. I'm not quite sure what you're thinking of that would have an OK button but not be a dialog.

Comment: +Joe White, I'm not sure what I'm thinking of either. I guess my fundamental problem stems from my use of Mvvm where I try to choose view model names that are ambiguous to the visual representation.

Comment: How about Default Action Buttons?

Comment: @jacksonPope what about Default Action Jackson Buttons. (I couldn't help it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joe White basically answered the question in the comments. He said "dialog buttons" are what they're called (by Microsofties, I'm assuming).

As for how that answer will be used within the context of my question (Mvvm/Wpf), I'm going to stick with my class name of CommitCancelViewModel since it is ambiguous regarding visual representation.